# 'Unknown column in where clause' in Delphi but not MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, dbexpress, dbx

I'm about ready to rip my hair out and take up poop flinging as a living!

I have a MySQL query which runs fine in MySQL

```
SELECT 
    p.ID AS DataID, 
    p.timestamp AS Timestamp, 
    sum(p.Value * v.Factor) AS Value,
    v.VirtualProfiles_id AS VProfileID 
FROM 
    profiledata p 
JOIN 
    profilevirtualjoin v 
ON 
    p.Profile_ID=v.Profile_ID 
WHERE 
    v.VirtualProfiles_id = 5
GROUP BY 
    v.Profile_ID, 
    p.timestamp
```

But when I try to run this as a query in a SQLDataSet in Delphi

```
SQLDataSet2.Active := False;
SQLDataSet2.CommandText := 'SELECT p.ID AS DataID, p.timestamp AS Timestamp, sum(p.Value * v.Factor) AS Value,' +
   'v.VirtualProfiles_id AS VProfileID FROM profiledata p JOIN profilevirtualjoin v ON ' +
   'p.Profile_ID=v.Profile_ID WHERE v.VirtualProfiles_id = ' + InttoStr(5)
   +' GROUP BY v.Profile_ID, p.timestamp';
SQLDataSet2.Active := True;
```

I get an error

```
First chance exception at $765BC41F. Exception class TDBXError with message 'Unknown column 'v.VirtualProfiles_id' in 'where clause''. Process EMVS.exe (7556)
```

If anyone can offer any insight, I would be most appreciative.

EDIT:

I am using the MySQL server 5.5 and Delphi XE

What I am trying to do is this:

I have a tables as follows:

```
Profile:
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Designation | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| UnitID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

profiledata
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TimeStamp  | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Value      | double   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Profile_ID | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Virtualprofiles
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Designation | varchar(45)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Unit_ID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

profilevirtualjoin
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| VirtualProfiles_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| Profile_ID         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| Factor             | double  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I need to do is to "produce" a new profile which is the sum of a set of existing profiles. so, the data from the profiledata table must be summed where the ProfileID is included in the virtualprofile and the timestamp values are equal.

Comment: Is the column written in the exacly same way in the query as it is in the database?

Comment: Try with WHERE WHERE v.VirtualProfiles_id =

Comment: yes, I've also tried to enclose the column name in ``, but to no avail

Comment: Seems like a driver problem to me. What is SQLDataSet and are you using an ODBC driver?

Comment: Sashi, using the double WHERE produces a syntax error

Comment: SQLDataSet is a VCL TSQLDataSet Component, and the driver is the DBX MySQL Driver

Comment: Please provide MySQL and Delphi versions you're using.

Comment: MySQL Server 5.5 and Delphi XE

Comment: It might be stupid, but did you try foregoing the aliases and using full names everywhere?

Comment: SWeko, no cigar. Same problem

Comment: I just tested this with Delphi XE3 and MySQL 5.1.33 and i did not get any error message. It seems to be a failure within Delphi XE

Comment: @Erik, have you by any chance created persistent fields on the `SQLDataSet2` (right-click the dataset, select "Add all fields")? If yes, remove them and try again.

Comment: I agree with @whosrdaddy, this looks like a MySQL DBX driver error - probably when parsing the SQL statement. Have you tried `sum((p.Value * v.Factor))`?

Comment: You could alternatively create a SP and pass `VirtualProfiles_id` to it.

Comment: No persistant fields @LightBulb. I've checked everywhere to update my DBX and MySQL Vendor library files, but the error persists. I've found a workaround that resolves the problem. I'll post it as an answer when my self-answer grace period has elapsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Problem

So, the problem is this. The DBExpress driver provided with Delphi **XE** can only process Dynamic SQL queries, not MySQL Queries. Although Dynamic SQL is compatible with MySQL, it is not compatible the other way around.

Quoting from the MySQL Manual (sec 12.16.3):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause.

The updated DBExpress driver included with Delphi **XE3** includes specific support for MySQL code, and so this limitation is not applicable.

### The Workaround

The solution to this problem is to create a view in MySQL server and to call it from Delphi using only Dynamic SQL compatible code. In the end the following workaround did the trick:

In MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW `VirtualProfileData` AS
SELECT 
    p.ID AS DataID, 
    p.timestamp AS Timestamp, 
    sum(p.Value * v.Factor) AS Value,
    v.VirtualProfiles_id AS VProfileID 
FROM 
    profiledata p 
JOIN 
    profilevirtualjoin v 
ON 
    p.Profile_ID=v.Profile_ID 
GROUP BY 
    v.Profile_ID, 
    p.timestamp
```

Then in Delphi

```
SQLDataSet2.Active := False;
SQLDataSet2.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM VirtualProfileData WHERE VProfileID = ' + InttoStr(5);
SQLDataSet2.Active := True;
```

Answer (score 1):

You changed the name of the column here:

```
v.VirtualProfiles_id AS VProfileID
```

After that point, in most cases (the exception being those involving grouping or aggregation), you need to refer to the column by the new name. I think that's the case here.

Try changing your `WHERE` clause to use the alias instead:

```
WHERE v.VirtualProfiles_id = ' + InttoStr(5)
```

Comment: I Tried removing the aliasing, and using the alias in the where clause. Both of these produced the same error as described above.

Comment: I've figured out a workaround. I'll post it as an answer as soon as my self-answer grace period has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the compatibility between Mysql Types and Delphi types try to use Basics Types of delphi

Comment: I'm afraid what you mentioned has nothing to do with this problem. The error comes in with the running of the query, which is passed only as a string. The problem is what is described in my answer to this question.

Comment: okey ! miss understanding of the problem because the problem of types happens to me with Dbexpress and i fix this problem by using ( DAC  FOR MYSQL Components ) .

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing from

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'VALUE';
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE 'VALUE';
```

solved the problem and return the same result.

I didn't dig dipper to figure it out what was happening, but it is a weird bug because it works fine with every other column except with a specific one.